# regex to match digit and full sto and replace it with empty char

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match digit and `.` and replacing it with `""` no char.

```
$buffer= "test. 8090";

if PREG_REPLACE('/[0-9]+[.]/', '', $buffer)
{
echo $buffer;
}
```

http://ideone.com/KgFm3I

What's wrong here? gives syntex error

Comment: the if condition should be wrapped with (): `if (PREG_REPLACE('/[0-9]+[.]/', '', $buffer)) ...`

Comment: `gives error` is not helping. You should at least specify which error message you get.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Don't put preg_replace inside the `if statement`,it  doesnot return true or false.

Change the regex pattern like this `\([\d+.])\`

```
preg_replace("/[.\d]+/", "", $buffer);
```

Comment: Why are you using parenthesis arround the character class? Also, the `+` is not a character to be replaced.

Comment: `+` in a character class means `+` literally, not one or more char. What group do you want to match, it' a nonsense in preg_replace. `.` doesn't need to be escaped in a character class. Spaces are not mandatory by OP.

Comment: Close ;-) the parenthesis are superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Put both digit and dot inside the character class `[]`

```
$new_str = PREG_REPLACE('/[0-9.]+/', '', $buffer);
                              ^ here goes the dot
```

Comment: At the end of your php script what is the `?` doing?? make it `?>`

Comment: You didn't use the code as I have given you. you are using a different one.

Comment: can you please upvote, dont know why people downvoted

Comment: @SabujHassan, That's weird mate. Happens.. Am upvoting.